# JavaScript Click event fires via the Enter Key but not via the Mouse

Tags: javascript, events, dom

Some code that looks like the following is firing the `click` event via the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key, but is not responding to the mouse click.

```
//a is an anchor element
a.addEventListener('click', function (e)
{
    //Do Stuff...
});
```

[This page](http://rodsbox.ue.okstate.edu/humphreys/grant/apply) demonstrates the problem. The relevant bit of code is at line 176. This is in the middle of development and currently only (sort of) works in **Chrome**.

Also, I just verified that it works if I use `mousedown`, so it's not just the case of an invisible element sitting in front of the anchor.

Any ideas?

Comment: This question tells us nothing about your code. Can you post a demo where it fails?

Comment: More code would help. But perhaps there is an invisible element blocking the anchor tag from actually being clicked?

Comment: @elclanrs et. al. - Demo posted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit: Now that you've shown us the actual code you're using, the problem is related to the fact that the `autoSuggest()` function has it's own click handler and in that click handler, it is clearing the container which removes all `<a>` elements in the container so your link object gets destroyed (probably before your click event gets to process).  So, you can get events that happen before the click (like mousedown), but after a click, the element is removed from the DOM.

If you tell us what you're trying to actually do when an auto-suggest item is clicked that is different than the default behavior of the `autoSuggest()` function and you point to any documentation for that function, then perhaps we could offer a better way to solve your issue.

---

The link may be firing and taking you off to a new page (or reloading the current page), thus preventing you from seeing the click code run.  Usually when you process a click event on a link element, you need to prevent the default behavior:

```
//a is an anchor element
a.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    //Do Stuff...
});
```

Another possibility is that you are trying to install the event handler too soon either before the DOM has been loaded or before this particular link has been created and thus no actual click event handler is attached to the DOM object.  You can verify whether the event handler is even getting called by temporarily putting an `alert("Click handler called");` in the event handler and see if that pops up or not.

Comment: Thanks. I'm already calling `e.preventDefault()`. I did just edit my question to include a link to a page that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: @RodrickChapman - see what I've added to the start of my answer.

Comment: Thanks so much. I actually wrote the `autosuggest` function and could have sworn that I used it in a similar way before.